# How can I change the name of the key in an object using "for ... in"

Tags: javascript

I want to use the for in function to change the keys.
I know I could do it with map but can it be done with for in?

```
 const meinObject = {
        name: "Dominic",
        plz: 9548,
    };

    for (let key in meinObject) {
        key + "1" + meinObject[key]
        console.log(key);
    }
```

Comment: An array of objects would be more convenient.

Comment: @Coding-is-fun 's answer could be used in the for in loop, but you'd have to check first if the new keys also get added to the for in loop (you want to avoid an infinite loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const meinObject = {
        name: "Dominic",
        plz: 9548,
    };

    for (let key in meinObject) {
        key + "1" + meinObject[key] // this does not make sense
        var value = meinObject[key]; // get dominic, then plz etc.
        console.log('original', key, value);
        
        meinObject[key] = 'overwrite!!!';
        var value = meinObject[key]; // get dominic, then plz etc.
        console.log('altered', key, value);
    }
    
    console.log('object after modification', meinObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you can do is assign the value of your key to a new key, then delete the old key. This does not use a for in loop, it is something simpler.

```
obj['newKey'] = obj['oldKey'];
delete obj['oldKey'];
```

or in your case

```
meinObject['key'] = meinObject['newKey']
delete meinObject['key']
```

Comment: But is there a way to do it with the for in loop similar to what i have drafted? I m not working on a project its just for studying purposes.

Comment: Why would you need to? I am sorry, I think I am misunderstanding your question.